# Python Dataframe rolling_sum with numbers not date

Tags: python, dataframe

Say part of my dataframe `df[(df['person_num'] == 1) | (df['person_num'] == 2) ]` looks like this:

```
person_num   Days    IS_TRUE
1            1       1
1            4       1
1            5       0
1            9       1
2            1       1
2            4       1
2            5       0
2            9       1
```

And for each `person_num`, I want to count something like "**how many `IS_TRUE=1` happens within seven days before a certain day**". So for Day 9, I count the number of `IS_TRUE=1`s from Day 2 to Day 8, and add the count to a new column `IS_TRUE_7day_WINDOW`. The result would be:

```
person_num    Days    IS_TRUE    IS_TRUE_7day_WINDOW
1             1       1          0
1             4       1          1
1             5       0          2
1             9       1          1
2             1       1          0
2             4       1          1
2             5       0          2
2             9       1          1
```

I'm thinking about using something like this:

```
df.groupby('person_num').transform(pd.rolling_sum, window=7,min_periods=1)
```

But I think rolling_sum only works for datetime, and the code doesn't work for my dataframe. Is there an easy way to convert `rolling_sum` to work for integers (`Days` in my case)? Or are there other ways to quickly compute the column I want?

I used `for` loops to calculate `IS_TRUE_7day_WINDOW`, but it took me an hour to get the results since my dataframe is pretty large. I guess something like `rolling_sum` would speed up my old code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implicitly do the `for` loop through vectorization, which will in general be faster than explicitly writing a `for` loop. Here's a working example on the data you provided:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Days': [1, 4, 5, 9, 1, 4, 5, 9],
                   'IS_TRUE': [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                   'person_num': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]})

def window(group):
    diff = np.subtract.outer(group.Days, group.Days)
    group['IS_TRUE_7day_WINDOW'] = np.dot((diff > 0) & (diff <= 7),
                                          group['IS_TRUE'])
    return group

f.groupby('person_num').apply(window)
```

Output is this:

```
   Days  IS_TRUE  person_num  IS_TRUE_7day_WINDOW
0     1        1           1                    0
1     4        1           1                    1
2     5        0           1                    2
3     9        1           1                    1
4     1        1           2                    0
5     4        1           2                    1
6     5        0           2                    2
7     9        1           2                    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned data frame derives from a database, consider an SQL solution using a subquery which runs the calculation in its engine and not directly in Python.

Below assumes a MySQL database but adjust library and connection string according to your actual backend (SQLite, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, etc.). Below should be ANSI-syntax SQL, compliant in most RDMS.

**SQL Solution**

```
import pandas pd
import pymysql  

conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost" port=3306,
                     user="username", passwd="***", db="databasename") 

sql = "SELECT t1.Days, t1.person_num, t1.IS_TRUE, \
        (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(t2.IS_TRUE),0)  \
           FROM TableName t2 \
          WHERE t2.person_num= t1.person_num \
            AND t2.Days >= t1.Days - 7  \
            AND t2.Days < t1.Days) AS IS_TRUE_7DAY_WINDOW \
       FROM TableName t1"

df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Days    person_num  IS_TRUE IS_TRUE_7DAY_WINDOW
   1             1        1                   0
   4             1        1                   1
   5             1        0                   2
   9             1        1                   1
   1             2        1                   0
   4             2        1                   1
   5             2        0                   2
   9             2        1                   1
```

Comment: As my question suggests, the dataframe in my example is `df[df['person_num'] == 1]`, so I want to calculate the `IS_TRUE_7day_WINDOW` for different `person_num`s, which needs `groupby` or something. Your code works for a single `person_num`, but I'm still having trouble with multiple `person_num`s(without using loops), since `df.groupby('person_num')['Days'].apply(f)` doesn't work. Are there ways to achieve my goal without using `for` loops? Thanks.

Comment: See update where a `groupby.apply()` is added before the series sum `apply()`. But my recreated `person_num` may be different than your data. By the way, does your dataframe originate from a database? I see an effortless SQL solution here. Otherwise, you require pandas to do a conditional running aggregate sum by group, not as efficient as a relational SQL engine.

Comment: Thanks for the update! And yes my dataframe came from a database, and I used SQL to extract the data. Could you give me the link to the effortless SQL solution? I really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Sorry but the results in your example is incorrect in my case. For the 3rd row, `IS_TRUE_7day_WINDOW` should be 0 for `person_num=2`.Please see my updated question, which is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The `rolling_`functions like `rolling_sum` use the index of the DataFrame or Series when seeing how far to go back. It doesn't have to be a datetime index. Below is some code to find the calculation for each user...

First use `crosstab` to make a DataFrame with a column for each `person_num` and a row for each day.

```
    >>> days_person = pd.crosstab(data['days'], 
                      data['person_num'], 
                      values=data['is_true'], 
                      aggfunc=pd.np.sum)
    >>> days_person
    person_num  1  2
    days
    1           1  1
    4           1  1
    5           0  0 
    9           1  1
```

Next I'm going to fill in missing days with 0's, because you only have a few days of data.

```
    >>> empty_data = {n: [0]*10 for n in days_person.columns}
    >>> days_person = (days_person + pd.DataFrame(empty_data)).fillna(0)
    >>> days_person
    person_num  1  2
    days
    1           1  1
    2           0  0
    3           0  0
    4           1  1
    5           0  0
    6           0  0
    7           0  0
    8           0  0 
    9           1  1
```

Now use `rolling_sum` to get the table you're looking for. Note that days 1-6 will have `NaN` values, because there weren't enough previous days to do the calculation.

```
    >>> pd.rolling_sum(days_person, 7)
```